# Identifying macros in a spreadsheet using LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Is there a way to find out what macros are in a LibreOffice Calc file?

I went to the menu **Tools > Macros > Organize Macros**, and reviewed all the options, but I am not seeing anything that tells me what macros are in use. Isn't there some way to detect what they are and make changes if desired?  It's a file created by someone else, and I have very basic knowledge of spreadsheets.

I could not find the answer in the Help files, which cover creating and organizing macros but do not give instructions on where to look just to see what macros are running in a file.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: I recommend to check the Apache OpenOffice wiki which usually has much better documentation that applies to LibreOffice, too. On organization of macros, see https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Macro_organization - maybe this already helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "in use" ?  You can easily see all the macros that have been written,   just by expanding the list that you seem to have found already.

Comment: @MikeBrockington,  I didn't see any lists.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screen-Shot]

Not intended as an answer to the question, but this is what I was talking about in comment on main question.

(Why can't I post an image as a comment???)

Comment: Ah, yes I see.  However, where you have something in your example called "Untitled1," I have nothing.  No macros listed, even though there apparently are macros in this file.  Even if I could see that file in the list, how would I know what it was made to do?